# T-SQL NTILE with less records

Tags: t-sql

I am using the T-SQL NTILE function like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(val int)
GO
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO #Temp(val) VALUES(3);

 SELECT val, Quantile
 FROM
(
    SELECT val, NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY val) AS Quantile
    FROM
    #Temp

) A


GO

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Unfortunately the resut:

val Quantile

1   1

2   2

3   3

is not what I am expecting.
I expect that the row is filled from right to left instead from left to right, when I have less that 10 records. This would make sense, because normally you like to distribute the data this way

This problem is mentioned in the community addon here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: You mean you'd want `1-8, 2-9, 3-10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want NTILE's behaviour, but filling from high to low instead. You can achieve this by subtracting `(n+1)-NTILE(n)` and order by descending, in your case;

```
SELECT val, Quantile FROM
(
    SELECT val, 11-NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY val DESC) AS Quantile
    FROM #Temp    
) A

> 1 -  8
> 2 -  9
> 3 - 10
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f5d0/1).